# Proper use of the React constructor?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my React Native project, I have a small array of objects (always less than 20) with IDs. The ID of the object I need is found in the navigation router, which is not available via Redux selector, I have to get it at the component level. So I am forced to do a little bit of logic. Is it ok for me to be using the `constructor` method this way?

```js
class DiscussionScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // Get discussion data using ID
    const discussion = props.discussions.find(
      item => item[ID] === props.navigation.getParam(ID)
    )

    // Pass to state
    this.state = {discussion}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Discussion
        discussion={this.state.discussion}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need `discussion` in `state`? As an alternative to your example, you could do this:

```js
class DiscussionScreen extends React.Component {
  _getDiscussion = () => this.props.discussions.find(
    item => item[ID] === this.props.navigation.getParam(ID)
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <Discussion
        discussion={this._getDiscussion}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: the way you have it you're missing `this` before `props`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the lifecycle methods to make changes in the state after setting it as empty object in constructor.
In my opinion, working with functions in constructor is not good in long runs.